# Access HttpServletRequest object inside Aspect. Which one is better solution between two solutions mentioned

Tags: java, spring, performance, aop

While trying to get request object in Aspect I found two solutions. I would like to know performance wise which one is better. Here are the details.

I wanted to execute myAspectMethod for all methods annotated by '@myAnnotation'. So where ever spring finds @myAnnotation at method level myAspectMethod will be executed where I am using request object to perform business logic. To get request I found two solutions

1. Inject request object in Aspect class like
   below

   ```
   @Aspect 
   public class MyAspect {
   @Autowired(required = true)
   **private HttpServletRequest request;**
   @Around("@annotation(myAnnotation)")
   public Object myAspectMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp,  
           MyAnnotation myAnnotation) throws Throwable {
           //....do something with request object
           }
   }
   ```
2. By sending request object as argument in annotated method and access it thru the argument list received

Access request in Aspect

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET }, value = "/something")
@MyAnnotation
public Object myAnnotatedMethod(**HttpServletRequest request**)
{
//....some business logic
}

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
@Around("@annotation(myAnnotation)")
    public Object myAspectMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp,
            MyAnnotation myAnnotation) throws Throwable {
            HttpServletRequest request = getRequestArgument(pjp);
            ....do something with request object
            }
    private HttpServletRequest getRequestArgument(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        for (Object object : pjp.getArgs()) {
            if (object instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
                return (HttpServletRequest) object;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

1. Between above two different ways of request object usage which one is better from performance perspective? This is important question for which I would like to know the answer.
2. What are the other pros and cons of each approach.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. I'm not sure that the first method works. Even if you can autowire `HttpServletRequest` this way, you'll have to make your aspect request-scoped.
2. I think the best option would be to use `RequestContextHolder`:

   ```
   HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
   ```

   This method uses a thread-local storage already populated by Spring and doesn't need any changes in your method signature.

Comment: Thank you @axtavt !

For solution#1 I thought something similar i.e. how request object can be injected into singleton Aspect. When I implemented and passed different requests with different header values, each time I get expected values. That mean each request object can be set into singleton bean. Looks like Spring handles it gracefully as per the scope. Here is the excellent article I come across
[http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection]

Comment: In Aspect, I want to formulate/change/update the Http Post request. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The first method did not work.

```
@Autowired(required = true)
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

did have the request specific data.

I am currently using the following to extract custom headers from my request

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) 
RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
request.getHeader("mycustom");
```